# How to properly stop an infinite CSS animation using webkitAnimationIteration event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, webkit

I'm having trouble stoping a CSS animation on every iteration accurately.
I Have a CSS animation that i want to play when i call a function and play it backwards again when i call another. For that i'm setting an infinite animation in CSS/javascript like this:

```
function setup(container, element){
   var elem = document.getElementById(container).getElementsByClassName(element)[0];
   elem.style.webkitAnimationName=elemento+"_move";
   elem.style.webkitAnimationDuration="350ms";
   elem.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
   elem.style.webkitAnimationDirection="alternate";
   elem.style.webkitAnimationIterationCount = "infinite";
   elem.addEventListener("webkitAnimationIteration", pause, false);
}
```

Notice that i'm setting an eventListener in the last line so that the animation pauses at every iteration using the fallowing function:

```
function pause(event){
    this.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
}
```

The function works fine when i play the animation forward, but when i use another function to set the 'WebkitAnimationPlayState' as 'running' and play is backwards it stops out of place. like one frame out of the place. 
Here is the function i use to put it back in motion:

```
function run(container, element){
    var elem = document.getElementById(container).getElementsByClassName(elemento)[0];
    elem.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
}
```

I don't know if it is one frame forward or backwards but avery time a try it the distance is different. I believe that the function pauses the animation a little before the real end of the iteration (Apple [Documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitAnimationEventClassReference/WebKitAnimationEvent/WebKitAnimationEvent.html) says it would be at the end).

Here is what i've done so far. 
  [DEMO](http://bitlock.com.br/arquivos/amima)

You can notice that the right border of the frame don't come back to where is was before the animation.

Anyone have a clue?
Thanks

Comment: Your animation is a little buggy, I can't tell what's happening on the page.

Comment: Hi. Are you using a Webkit browser? Here its working on Safari and Chrome. What you see there? Thanks

Comment: Okay I see it now. Must've been looking away, but it stops only at the end.

Comment: What i meant to do is to "open" and "close" the div, but when it closes the right edge don't come to where it was in the first place. Same happens to you? thanks